# Turning Nested JSON with Arrays into DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

I have a heavily nested set of Json that I would like to turn into a table

I would like to turn the below JSON response into a table under "steps" I could just extract "name" and "options" and there values

```
    "data": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "sections": [
                    {
                        "steps": [
                            {
                                "blocking": false,
                                "actionable": true,
                                "document": null,
                                "name": "Site",
                                "options": [
                                    "RKM",
                                    "Meridian"
                                ],
                                "description": null,
                                "id": "036c3090-95c4-4162-a746-832ed43a2805",
                                "type": "DROPDOWN"
                            },
                            {
                                "blocking": false,
                                "actionable": true,
                                "document": null,
                                "name": "Location",
                                "options": [
                                    "Field",
                                    "Station"
                                ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json['data']['activities'][0]['sections'][0]['steps'])[['name', 'options']]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       name           options
0      Site   [RKM, Meridian]
1  Location  [Field, Station]
```

Comment: What if I also want the other stuff in my datadrame as well such as "blocking" actionable" etc etc. That is the part I am struggling with. @U10-Forward

Comment: @ZachGodsell Then do: `df = pd.DataFrame(json['data']['activities'][0]['sections'][0]['steps'])[['name', 'options', 'blocking', 'actionable']]`, just add more keys to the last list

Comment: @ZachGodsell If you want all of the columns remove the whole list from the end

Comment: what if all of the Json looks like this, and I want all of this data in the data frame. What would be the best way to approach it to clarify: https://pastebin.com/qyYpf5RN

Comment: @ZachGodsell I would mind you to ask this as another question, so since this answered the question that you posted, you should accept it